# Dynamic Breadcrumbs in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, breadcrumbs

P.S I'm a newbie in codeigniter and searched for answers but its far beyond my comprehension so I will ask this question for my level.

I just found this code for a dynamic breadcrumb helper in youtube and I am receiving an error. Can you guys help me debug it? Cause I'm confuse with his code but its an efficient one cause you just simply echo the function in VIEW.
This is the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Parsing Error
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected ';'
>
> Filename: helpers/breadcrumb_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 15
>
> Backtrace:

Here is the code

```
    <?php
if(!function_exists('generatedBreadcrumb')){
    function generateBreadcrumb(){
        $ci=&get_instance();
        $i=1;
        $iro = $ci->iri->segment($i);
        $link='
        <div class="pageheader">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>'.$ci->uri->segment($i).'</h2>
        <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">

        <ol class="breadcrumb">';

        while($uri != "){
        $prep_link = ";
        $for($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++){
        $prep_link.=$ci->uri->segment($j).'/';
        }

        if($ci->uri->segment($i+1)=="){
            $link.='<li class="active"><a href=".site_uri($prep_link).">';
            $link.=$ci->uri->segment($i).'</a></li>';
        }else{
            $link.='<li><a href=."site_url($prep_link).">';
            $link.=$ci->uri->segment($i).'</a><span class="divider"></span></li>';
        }

        $i++;
        $uri = $ci->uri->segment($i);
        }
        $link .='</ol></div></div>';
        return $link;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `$variables` with one double quote not two, like this:

```
while($uri != "){}
```

should be:

```
while($uri != ''){}
```

And also this:

```
$prep_link = ";
```

should be:

```
$prep_link = '';
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!function_exists('generatedBreadcrumb')){
        function generateBreadcrumb(){
            $ci=&get_instance();
            $i=1;
            $uri = $ci->uri->segment($i);
            $link='
            <div class="pageheader">
            <h2><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>'.$ci->uri->segment($i).'</h2>
            <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">

            <ol class="breadcrumb">';

            while($uri != ''){
            $prep_link = '';
            for($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++){
            $prep_link.=$ci->uri->segment($j).'/';
            }

            if($ci->uri->segment($i+1)== ''){
                $link.='<li class="active"><a href="'.site_url($prep_link).'">';
                $link.=$ci->uri->segment($i).'</a></li>';
            }else{
                $link.='<li><a href="'.site_url($prep_link).'">';
                $link.=$ci->uri->segment($i).'</a><span class="divider"></span></li>';
            }

            $i++;
            $uri = $ci->uri->segment($i);
            }
            $link .='</ol></div></div>';
            return $link;
            }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Getting error of

> Fatal error: Call to a member function segment() on null in
>   breadcrumb_helper.php

You have also changed the following, like this:

```
$iro = $ci->iri->segment($i);
```

should be:

```
$uri = $ci->uri->segment($i);
```

And so on.